# Onclick property is not working of RatingBar in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

The below code is not working when I click on RatingBar in App. Please Help...

**Note: I have set the property of RatingBar Onclick with rate.**

```
public void rate(View v) {
    RatingBar r1 = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(r1.getRating()) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

[image: Rating Bar and Properties Panel]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443939/ratingbar-onclick

Comment: public void On **C** lickListener 'C' is upper case

Comment: hi petrov, that code is working. i want to know about rate function

Comment: hi sasikumr, i wana run in this way, not through the listener.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you would like to be informed whenever users set the rating, so you would need `OnRatingBarChangeListener` not `OnClickListener`.

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

    }
});
```

**Note:** `onClick` method of `OnClickListener` interface is getting called by another method called `performClick()`. This method is declared in the `View` class, so click event all is handled in `View` class. However `RatingBar` *overrides* internal touch event callbacks and does not allow the root class (i.e. `View`) to be informed. So, the underlying `View` cannot detect click events anymore. A workaround nevertheless, could be in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010379/1841194).

Comment: but i want to run through OnClick property.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `Onclick` property is not working is that `RatingBar` overrides `onTouchEvent()` . so `ratingBar.setOnClickListener()` is never called.

use `OnTouchListener` instead of `onClickListener`.